# Using Auslogics on wine

Tags: wine

I'm installing auslogics in my laptop to run it with wine. When I try to defrag disk or flash disk, it says

> unable to access the drive. try rebooting and running  defragmentation again

How can I configure wine to allow this program to access hard disk or flash drive?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are you trying to run Auslogics on Ubuntu? Defragmentation, anti-virus, boost? Issue could be that auslogic actually plays with windows registry which doesn’t exist on Ubuntu. Could you be more specific what are you doing or planing to do with auslogics?

Comment: i wanna defrag my flash disk with auslogics, so you said that i can't defrag my drive or flashdisk?i wanna play ps 2 with usb so the game must bu defragmented using auslogics. ahhh i see. thankyou very much dani and oli thankyou

Comment: yap it wont work through Wine, Windows is one thing wine is something different. I frankly don’t see how to use auslogics to defrag thumb drive on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to agree with danijelc's comment and expand on it: **auslogics *can't* work through Wine**. This sort of system utility is designed to fix Windows. Wine isn't the same thing.

- No direct access to filesystems to defragment them (Wine abstracts everything)
- Even if you could con it into scanning a raw disk, Auslogics probably won't understand the filesystems you try to pass it
- Registry access will only give you access to a Wine registry which shouldn't be too bad anyway. If it is *that* clogged up, consider starting a clean prefix.

Comment: ahh thankyou for explaining to me. is there any program on ubuntu can defrag my flashdisk?or using terminal to defrag it?

Comment: You will need to do it with Windows.

Comment: @user245288 [shake might work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213421/can-ubuntu-defragment-ntfs-or-fat-drives) but I'm not sure I'd worry about fragmentation on a flash drive as the random seek speed is so fast. Fragmentation affects spinning disks because the read head has to physically move to a new location.

Comment: ahhh i see so if i use shake, i still can't defrag my flash disk? maybe im going to double boot in my laptop. thanks guys for answering my question :D